# how to measure SSO success?

Tags: force.com, reporting, single-sign-on

I want to get a sense of how many users are using SSO, is there a way to get those #'s?  Better yet- Could I get a list of users who are not using SSO, and logging in normally?

One little caveat is that we use Salesforce for Outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT count(id), userid FROM LoginHistory WHERE LoginType = 'SAML Sfdc Initiated SSO' group by userid
```